# error in barcode Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, barcode, zend-framework2

I have a question about Barcode generation in Zend Framework 2.

All the time I get an error :

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Validator/Barcode.php
>   on line 110

The code I use is :

```
    // Only the text to draw is required
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');

    // No required options
    $rendererOptions = array();

    $imageResource = Barcode::factory(
        'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
    )->render();

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($imageResource);
```

When I delete the render function chained to the `barcode::factory` I see a `'Zend\Barcode\Renderer\Image'` object. When I run the render function I get the error.

I've got the code from the Zend Framework documentation. I couldn't find good ZF2 documentation about this. Has anybody had this problem before? What can I do about it?

Comment: The barcode code is not ported to Zend Framework 2 yet. Many components need to be refactored to the latest standard and this component has not been transformed yet. You can either use Zend Framework 1 or wait until Zend Framework 2 has become stable.

Comment: Ok, that explaines a lot :) Weird that the files are in the download if it's not working at all. I have made a complete project in ZF2 and this is the final part. Is there some other library you can recommend for creating barcodes? I use the code39 type barcode.

Comment: you might try to fix the code and send the patches back. This will help the community a lot and I think this is not a very hard problem to solve. The Zend\Loader is deprecated and I think if you remove lines 107-109 your error will be gone: https://github.com/juriansluiman/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/Barcode.php#L107